# Conversion of double to int

Tags: java, type-conversion

I want to input the W into the int array. How can i do that? Sorry for the lousy question or english.

```
public void setX (int Y , double W)
{       
  array[Y] = W;
}
```

Comment: You will lose the decimal part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're happy to truncate towards 0 - and get `int.MIN_VALUE` or `int.MAX_VALUE` if the value is out of the range of `int` - you can just cast:

```
array[Y] = (int) W;
```

If you're *not* happy with those caveats, you should re-evaluate your design - think about what you *want* to happen, e.g. if `W` is `15.25`. If you need to preserve all the original information, you should use a `double[]` rather than an `int[]`.

(You should also revisit your parameter names, if those are your *real* names. Read up on Java naming conventions.)

Comment: You could try rounding the value first `array[Y] = (int) Math.round(W);`

Comment: The W will be like 7.5 or something with decimal and not to be round off. What should i do? Please advice. Many Thanks

Comment: @WillieHii: Well how can it not be rounded at all if your array is of integers? What do you want the value of the array element to be afterwards? It can't be 7.5...

Answer (score -1):

The `array[Y]` should be delcared be fore you asign and the Y would be smaller than the size of this array.

```
array[Y] = Integer.valueOf(W + "");
```

Above line would help

Comment: It's not clear what you think this is an answer to, but it's not addressing the question asked.

Comment: That still wouldn't compile - which overload of `Integer.valueOf` would you expect it to use?

Comment: Sorry , what i try to find out is i need to input the value such as 15.5. So i might need to convert int to double ?

Comment: So there only the way @JonSkeet mentioned would help. I'm trying to find out another way.

Comment: @Trobbins , if i change my array to double, my Y will need to be double as well, but i would like to keep it as interger only.

Comment: @lethanh: That will now compile, but throw an exception at execution time due to the string not being a valid integer (it end with ".0" even if the original value happens to be equal to an integer). Why would you *want* to format the number as a string and then parse it? Ick.

Comment: so there no way to use the Integer class for this task?